# Unable to output stream to blob after latest webjob update 0.3.0

Tags: azure, azure-webjobssdk

I'm using the azure webjobs and as output on a job I write a stream to a blob like this

```
[Blob("unapproved/{Name}")] Stream image
```

So far it worked fine, but after updating to ver. 0.3.0, I get a binding exception on this one. Should it work or is the way forward to implement the ICloudBlobStreamBinder?

Looking at the sample here http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/06/18/announcing-the-0-3-0-beta-preview-of-microsoft-azure-webjobs-sdk/ It's easy when both input and output is a blob. But in my situation I get a message from a queue as the trigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Blob attribute constructor overload that has two arguments. The second argument is the file access. The Stream will be either readable or writable, based on the value that pass to this argument.